# How would you make a Graphics3D that has Labels for +x and -x?

Tags: graphics3d, labeling

So I'd like to make a graphic of a 3D cave network, and so I'd like to have labels on the axes indicating north, south, east, west, up, and down.  The way that I imagine doing this is by labeling each half-axis with the direction it's pointing in (eg +x->"North", -x->"South", etc).  However, so far as I can see there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with `AxesLabel`.

Is there a way to label half axes like this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to label half axes like this?

I would make them manually.

```
Graphics3D[
 {Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}],
  Style[Text["+X->Noth", {3.3, 0, 0}, {-1, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["-X->South", {-3.3, 0, 0}, {1, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["Y", {0, 3, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["Z", {0, 0, 3}], Bold, 16]},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
 Axes -> True,
 PreserveImageOptions -> False,
 Ticks -> None,
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Formatting, positioning, fonts, etc... can be improved of course.

> I'd like to have labels on the axes indicating north, south, east,
>   west, up, and down

```
Graphics3D[
 {Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}],
  Style[Text["East", {3.3, 0, 0}, {-1, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["West", {-3.3, 0, 0}, {1, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["North", {0, 3.3, 0}, {-1, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["South", {0, -3.3, 0}, {1, 0}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["Up", {0, 0, 3.3}], Bold, 16],
  Style[Text["Down", {0, 0, -3.3}], Bold, 16]}
 ,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
 Axes -> True,
 PreserveImageOptions -> False,
 Ticks -> None,
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]